# Show that if $|f-g|\leq\varepsilon$ then $|\underline\int_{a}^{b}f-\underline\int_{a}^{b}g|\leq\varepsilon(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose that $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are bounded such that $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq\varepsilon$ for each $x\in[a,b]$, for some $\varepsilon>0$.

Show that $|\underline\int_{a}^{b}f-\underline\int_{a}^{b}g|\leq\varepsilon(b-a)$, where
\begin{align}
\underline\int_{a}^{b}f = \sup_{\mathcal{P}} l(f,\mathcal{P})
\end{align}
is the lower (Riemann) integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$.

**My attempt based on the hint by Keen-ameteur:**

Let $\delta>0$. Pick a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a,b]$ such that
\begin{align}
\underline\int_{a}^{b}f \leq l(f,\mathcal{P}) + \frac{\delta}{2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\underline\int_{a}^{b}g \leq l(g,\mathcal{P}) + \frac{\delta}{2}.
\end{align}

Assume w.l.o.g that $l(f,\mathcal{P}) \geq l(g,\mathcal{P})$. Since $f \leq g + \varepsilon$ we get that
\begin{align}
|l(f,\mathcal{P}) - l(g,\mathcal{P})| &= l(f,\mathcal{P}) - l(g,\mathcal{P}) \\
&\leq l(g+\varepsilon,\mathcal{P}) - l(g,\mathcal{P}) \\
 &=\varepsilon(b-a).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint I would suggest is using the triangle inequality. i.e., find some sizes $A_\delta,B_\delta$ such that

$$ \Bigg \vert \underline\int_{a}^{b}f-A_\delta\Bigg\vert+ \vert A_\delta-B_\delta\vert + \Bigg\vert B_\delta- \underline\int_{a}^{b}g \Bigg\vert \leq\varepsilon(b-a)+\delta, $$

for all $\delta>0$.

For $A_\delta$ and $B_\delta$, you should have candidates which follow form the definition of $\underline{\int_a^b}$.